# The causes of the nodal precession of a satellite in Earth orbit?

Tags: planets, orbital-motion

All artificial satellites in Earth orbit between the polar orbit and the equatorial orbit are subject to a nodal precession caused by the equatorial bulge of the Earth at the equator.

How the equatorial bulge of the Earth can attract and deflect artificial satellites?

Is it because there is slightly more mass at the equator and this causes a slightly stronger gravitational force on the satellite as it gets closer to the equator?

Is it because at the equator a greater part of the mass is found towards the outside (less concentrated in the center of the Earth) and then the force of attraction of gravity pulls the satellite a little more towards the surface from the equator than to the center of the Earth?

Or some other reason?

Comment: *Great first question!* Welcome to Stack Exchange. Nodal precession questions are usually answered by simply pasting $$\omega_p = -\frac{3}{2} \frac{R_E^2}{(a(1-\epsilon^2))^2)}J_2 \omega \cos i$$ from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_precession#Equation) without reference to how it was derived.

Comment: See also: [ISS nodal precession](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50913/iss-nodal-precession) and [Why is Nodal precession affected by the rotational period of the planet?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26715/why-is-nodal-precession-affected-by-the-rotational-period-of-the-planet/29535#29535)

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome which of course do exactly what I mentioned above - simply paste (and use) the equation from Wikipedia. :-)

Comment: @uhoh Agree!  Neither of those really explain where the expression comes from.

Comment: I admit I don't really understand, even with this formula.

Comment: In Vallado's "Fundamentals of Astrodynamics and Applications" he derives the equation quoted by uhoh above.  He goes through the physics over several pages, but the most succinct explanation he gives is "The orbit behaves like a spinning top undergoing a torque and precesses as shown.  Recall that the rate of change of the angular-momentum vector of a precessing top aligns with the applied-torque vector; thus, in the figure above the angular momentum moves to the left because the torque effect of the equitorial buldge is in the negative I-J direction".

Comment: I'll add that he actually calls the effect "nodal regression".  And the diagram he's referencing in the quote above is a simulation with $ J_2 $ at 10 times its normal value.

Comment: Another source, Veris' "Practical Astrodynamics" Vol 1 goes into even more detail than Vallado's book.

Comment: @GregMiller while talking about an orbit as if it were a rigid body might feel succinct, it is - to me at least - useless without an explanation of why the orbit can be treated as a rigid rotor. I think an answer drawing some highlights from the less succinct "the physics over several pages" would be exactly what's needed here. *Go for it?*

Comment: @SebastyenLaroche I'd love to see an answer to this question; I could add another bounty, or you could consider asking to have it migrated to perhaps Math SE or Physics SE.

Comment: @uhoh How do I migrate my question to Physic SE?

Comment: @SebastyenLaroche Site moderators handle migration. Under your post there are little commands like "Edit" and "Share" and "Flag". Click "Flag" and select the "Something Else" option and just leave a short message asking for assistance to migrate to Physics SE since even a bounty hasn't been able to produce an answer here in Astronomy.

Comment: Thank you @uhoh